# Jquery/JSON issue

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to use the following code to get the availability of a domain name

```
var domurl = 'http://XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/domchek.php?domname=google.com';

$.getJSON(domurl, {data: "available"}, function(json) {
  $("#enterone").html(json.available);
});
```

The JSON returned is

```
{"status":"success","domain":"google","available":false}
```

If I use

```
  $("#enterone").html(json.status);
```

It returns success as expected but if I try and return available it returns nothing. My guess is because false is not a string (domain also works)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix could be

```
$.getJSON(domurl, {data: "available"}, function(json) {
  $("#enterone").html(json.available + '');
});
```